# Handling multiple jQuery versions conflicts when loading jQuery to third-party pages

Tags: jquery, conflict

I'm creating some JavaScript, mainly jQuery based widgets that are suppose to work on third-party pages. To simplify embedding and maintenance of the widgets, we are asking users to embed only one `<script>` element snippet that downloads a JavaScript file from our server which further downloads all the CSS and JavaScript needed for widget to run, and places them in head of the third-party page.

My problem happens with pages that already have jQuery, which is one of the dependent JavaScript. Our widget uses `var jQuery_1_6 = jQuery.noConflict(true)` which is set right after jQuery is loaded, however, in the script that check whether jQuery is loaded we use the following `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')` and `if (typeof jQuery.ui == 'undefined')`.

Now the thing is if there is already `jQuery` and `jQuery.ui` on the page, the `if`s will not load jQuery version, which (I guess) causes `jQuery_1_6 = jQuery.noConflict(true)` not to work.

Any ideas how to apply `noConflict` on already loaded jQuery? Would it help to append again the nodes that already loaded jQuery, and if so, how to figure out which .js file hosts jQuery code?

Comment: see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: Hi Manuel, just to respect you effort as weel, the difference between the thread you suggested and what I need is, that we don't require users to add any script elements in head, rather we load it dynamically, which results in the problem I described. Thank you anyhow, best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

Comment: Wow, nailed it right in the head. It is exactly what I'm doing. Thanks Sathis. By the way, my first question on stackoverflow, I'm pretty impressed.